# Problems with spatie laravel-media library using uuid

Tags: laravel, laravel-medialibrary

I am trying to use the spatie "laravel-media library 10" with laravel 9 and models using uuids.

The media will be attached to the users. So my user class is :

```
 use Spatie\MediaLibrary\HasMedia;
use Spatie\MediaLibrary\InteractsWithMedia;

class User extends Authenticatable implements HasMedia
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable, HasUuid, HasCreatedUpdatedBy;
    use InteractsWithMedia;

    public $incrementing = false;

    protected $keyType = 'string';
```

As my user uses uuid for the key, I must declare using my own model (see the spatie [documentation here](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-medialibrary/v8/advanced-usage/using-your-own-model)

And so I added a class "Media" :

```
namespace App\Models;

use Spatie\MediaLibrary\MediaCollections\Models\Media as BaseMedia;

class Media extends BaseMedia
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'uuid';

    protected $keyType = 'string';

    public $incrementing = false;

    // ...
}
```

And I declared it in the config "media-library.php" file :

```
/*
     * The fully qualified class name of the media model.
     */
    //'media_model' => Spatie\MediaLibrary\MediaCollections\Models\Media::class,
    'media_model' => App\Models\Media::class,
```

In the UserController, I try to associate the uploaded image to an user like that :

```
$user->addMedia($request->image_user)->toMediaCollection('images_user');
```

I cleared the caches, restarted the server etc... And I have still this error :

**SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation: 7 ERREUR: syntaxe en entrée invalide pour l'entier : « 7f3c4d07-1e0b-4897-b3cf-8d8f9fca7296 » (SQL: select max("order_column") as aggregate from "media" where "model_type" = App\Models\User and "model_id" = 7f3c4d07-1e0b-4897-b3cf-8d8f9fca7296)**

It means that the library still considers that my user key is an integer. What can I do more ?

**EDIT**

I modified the migration file pour the media table :

before :

```
Schema::create('media', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->bigIncrements('id');
    
                $table->morphs('model');
```

after :

```
 Schema::create('media', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');

            $table->uuidMorphs('model');
```

And now all works fine.
But was it the good method ?